# textbox isReadonly to change with combobox selecteditem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, textbox

I have datatemplate and list of 5 rows. So in every row, there is combobox with two comboboxitems "yes" and "no". So when the window is loaded, textboxes inside ListBox rows are set to readonly="True" inside the Datatemplate. But when I select "no" from combobox items in individual row, then textbox should become editable and isReadonly="False" for each individual row in the List. My ListBox items are 5. How to do this?

```
//xaml
 <ListBox x:Name="wbListDataTemplate"  
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding wbVisibleItems}"         
                                  DataContext="{DynamicResource wbItem}" 
                                  Background="{x:Null}"  
                                 SelectedItem="{Binding wbSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}"
                                 IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Canvas.Top="33"  Height="152" Width="628" LostFocus="wbListDataTemplate_LostFocus" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Initialized="wbListDataTemplate_Initialized_1">

                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>                                
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" Height="39" Width="642" Margin="0,0,0,-14" >
                                        <Grid x:Name="Grid1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="697"  Margin="10,0,0,0" Height="54" >

                                            <Label Margin="0,3,0,5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>


                                            <ComboBox x:Name="wbselect" Margin="0,0,60,1" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Loaded="wbselect_Loaded" >
                                                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="wbyes" IsSelected="True" Content="yes"></ComboBoxItem>
                                                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="wbno" Content="no"></ComboBoxItem>
                                            </ComboBox>                                          
                                            <TextBox x:Name="wbdepth" Text="" MaxLength="20" Margin="217,0,230,1" LostKeyboardFocus="wbdepth_LostKeyboardFocus" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsReadOnly="True"/>       

                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                           
                        </ListBox>
```

Comment: straight = yes and tapered = no?

Comment: @MightyBadaboom please check the edit now

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I would recommend against using a ComboBox for this purpose (and prefer to use a CheckBox or ToggleButton), you may use a DataTrigger on the `SelectedIndex` property of the ComboBox in a TextBox Style:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cb" SelectedIndex="0">
            <ComboBoxItem>Yes</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>No</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=cb}"
                                     Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an `IValueConverter` which could look like this.

```
public class ReadonlyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var content = ((ComboBoxItem)value).Content;
        var isEnabled = content.Equals("yes");

        return isEnabled;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And in your xaml you have to change

```
IsReadOnly="True"
```

to

```
IsReadOnly="{Binding ElementName=wbselect, Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource ReadOnlyConverter}}"
```

And you have to add a reference to your converter

```
<Window xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Converters">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converter:ReadonlyConverter x:Key="ReadOnlyConverter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
```